# SQL commands supported within Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, notsupportedexception

I'm trying to execute a series of SQL statements from within a Stored Procedure in SnowFlake (v3.49.2) and it's throwing errors when executing certain commands, e.g.,

"Unsupported statement type 'SET'."

Would there be a list of SQL commands which are supported/unsupported when executed within Stored Procedures?

Comment: I think this is specific to SnowFlake. You can check the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/set.html). Ideally, you would post the code along with the question, so we can get a better idea about the context. Most of the times this helps, even if you think it might be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Found a list of what's supported here - https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html

In short - any commands which can could affect other user's sessions are prohibited.